# argument dependent lookup not considered

Tags: c++, templates, argument-dependent-lookup

Why argument dependent lookup doesn't consider `Foo::dynamicCast`, shouldn't it consider namespace Foo because the Base class is in this namespace?

```
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

namespace Foo
{

template<typename P, typename T> P*
dynamicCast(T* t)
{
    return dynamic_cast<P*>(t);
}

class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

}

namespace Test
{

class Derived : public Foo::Base
{
};

}

shared_ptr<Foo::Base> b = make_shared<Test::Derived>();
auto d = dynamicCast<Test::Derived>(b.get());
```

Comment: tested a little. This works: http://ideone.com/tX3JcU

Comment: ADL isn't triggered when using explicit template arguments.

Comment: @0x499602D2: A little more complicated: except if there is a visible function template of the same name: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15b614250f6ad61c).

Answer (score 4):

In order to even understand that you have a function call with a template, and not a bunch of `<` and `>` operators, the compiler must know you have a function template; and in order to understand that, it must know what namespace to look it up in. And in order to know that, it must understand the namespaces of the function arguments. And in order to understand *that* it must know there *are* function arguments around. Which, as we have seen, depends on knowing that there's a function call to begin with. Which the compiler doesn't know until it finds a template declaration. See the problem?

Because of that, ADL is only ever considered if the postfix-expression in the function call is an *unqualified-id*. Which `dynamicCast<Test::Derived>` is <s>not</s> **<edit>** only if `dynamicCast` is known to be a *template-name*, which is determined during normal unqualified lookup, which doesn't look into the namespace where the template is declared.

As @T.C. observed, one can declare an unrelated function template named `dynamicCast` in the global namespace in order to make ADL work.

**</edit>**

In a better world we would have an option to write `template foo<whatever>` in any context and disambiguate the angle brackets. Maybe in C++20.

Comment: `dynamicCast<Test::Derived>` **is** an *unqualified-id*, **if** `dynamicCast` is a *template-name*. A `template<int> void dynamicCast() = delete;` that is picked up by normal unqualified lookup is sufficient to make ADL work.

Comment: @T.C. you're right of course, my std::fu is slow today.

Answer (score 3):

Template functions with explicit template arguments are not found via ADL.  Maybe a parsing problem, do not know why.

Another example is `std::get`.  You cannot `get<3>(some_tuple)` without a using statement.

You can work around this by passing the arguments you would pass as template args as tag types.  You can also do a one-two step external function plus internal ADL tag dispatched lookup (so the public function has to be qualified, but customization points of the internal tag-based ADL can be done).

```
// tag utilities:
template<class T>struct tag_t{using type=T;constexpr tag_t(){};};
template<class T>constexpr tag_t<T> tag={};

namespace some{
  template<class T, class U>
  T* dynamic(tag_t<T>, U* u){
    return dynamic_cast<T>(u);
  }
  struct bob{};
}
```

Now `dynamic(tag<int>,new some::bob{})` will find `dynamic` via ADL.

I do not have chapter and verse from the standard for you.

Comment: I'm guessing the `U/]*u` is your hand falling asleep on the keyboard?

Comment: @Barry fat phone fingers.

Comment: I'm impressed you can type all of that on your phone!